# Best Practice setting up PHP mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there's a common best practice for setting up a mysql connection object in a php program so that you don't write redundant connection code over and over in your classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that you don't write redundant connection code over and over in your classes" ?

Comment: One related, critical consideration:  You want to protect the connection parameters from exposure, so you want them off any directory path that a browser could get to.  Encapsulating that bit of code is a step toward security, as you have it in only one (secure) location.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Repository Pattern ( http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html ) to put all of my database and SQL code into a small set of classes that are responsible for translating between the database and domain objects. This keeps all of the other code from having redundant db connection code or SQL queries.

I use it like this:

```
$criteria = new UserCriteria();
$criteria->active = true;
$repository->getUsers($criteria); // repo connects to DB and returns array of user objects
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute right way of doing it but you can take other people's suggestions and perhaps combine them.

My idea is that you could require a file that prepares a connection and then declare a Global Variable and use that variable to execute all of your queries.

Comment: This is the way I normally do it, although the 'factory method' above looks best in my opinion